# C#/ASP.NET - Cannot have repeater inside HTMLselect

Tags: c#, .net, repeater, html-select

I'm trying to display some data within a select using the following code:

```
<select name="area" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterArea" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <option value="<%# Eval('Id') %>" runat="server"><%# Eval("Area") %></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

I get an error stating that I cannot have a repeater inside a HTMLSelect.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `runat="server"`. You can get the value by `Request.Form["area"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `<select>` being run at the server? Remove that attribute and it should compile fine.

As the error says, the only valid child element of an `HtmlSelect` are options or optgroup thingy, not asp repeaters (even if they do create options, the compiler isn't aware of this).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the runat="server" from select tag

Comment: Thanks, but will I be able to use the value in a POST etc?

Comment: The value you will be able to use through FormCollection

Comment: If it is not suitable for you, you would need to bind the select element using code behind