# Error: 'HtmlSelect' cannot have children of type 'Repeater'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display some data within a select using the following code:

```
<select id="optionsSelectEmployeeType" runat="server" style="color: white; background-color: #6C6D70; font-size: 14px;">
        <option value="0">Select an employee Type</option>
             <asp:Repeater ID="EmployeeTypesList" runat="server">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <option value='<%#Eval("EmployeeType") %>'><%#Eval("EmployeeType") %></option>
                     </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

However I get the following error:

'HtmlSelect' cannot have children of type 'Repeater'.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong please?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#/ASP.NET - Cannot have repeater inside HTMLselect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661030/c-asp-net-cannot-have-repeater-inside-htmlselect)

Comment: @Vivek Did you acheive this? I also in same problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `runat="server"` from Select tag.

So the code will

```
<select id="optionsSelectEmployeeType" style="color: white; background-color: #6C6D70; font-size: 14px;">
        <option value="0">Select an employee Type</option>
             <asp:Repeater ID="EmployeeTypesList" runat="server">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <option value='<%#Eval("EmployeeType") %>'><%#Eval("EmployeeType") %></option>
                     </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

Comment: IF I remove runat="server" its working without any error, but I need to get this option value at code behind. How can I achieve that ??

Comment: You can acces via Request.Form["optionsSelectEmployeeType"]??